# Adding in cloudwatch events to emr cluster

Tags: boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

With the boto3 library, I want to  create an EMR cluster, then create events based off of cluster changes using cloud watch events.

So I can create the cluster, but I'm a bit confused with how the [CloudWatchEvents section of boto3 works](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/events.html#CloudWatchEvents.Client.put_rule).

According to the documentation for CWE in the boto3 library, there's a parameter to `put_rule` called `EventPattern` that is a string.  It's described as the following:

**EventPattern** *(string)* -- The event pattern. For more information, see [Events and Event Patterns](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEventsandEventPatterns.html) in the Amazon CloudWatch Events User Guide .

Following the link provided in the description, it shows a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
  "source": [ "aws.ec2" ],
  "detail-type": [ "EC2 Instance State-change Notification" ],
  "detail": {
    "state": [ "running" ]
  }
}
```

As I understand it, this is for custom events, but EMR provides [events for CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#emr_event_type).

If I was to follow the pattern provided for an EMR event, would I need to provide a string that looked like this?

```
{
    "source": ["aws.emr"],
    "detail-type": "EMR Cluster State Change",
    "detail": {
         "clusterid": <clusterid>,
         "state": "STARTING"
    }
}
```

Is there some flaw with this logic?  I'm a bit confused how it all fits together with the boto docs.

I've tried converting the dictionary to a string by using the following code:

```
    client.put_rule(
    Name='Cluster_starting',
    EventPattern=str({
        "source": ["aws.emr"],
        "detail-type": "EMR Cluster State Change",
        "detail": {
            "clusterid": cluster_id,
            "state": "STARTING"
        }
    }),
    State="ENABLED"
)
```

but got back the following error:

```
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidEventPatternException: An error occurred (InvalidEventPatternException) when calling the PutRule operation: Event pattern is not valid. Reason: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [Source: {'source': ['aws.emr'], 'detail-type': 'EMR Cluster State Change', 'detail': {'state': 'STARTING', 'clusterid': '<cluster_id>'}}; line: 1, column: 3]
```

Comment: Yep, the fact that all individual elements in the pattern must be specified as lists is counter-intuitive, and AWS documentation does not state that explicitly

Answer (score 2):

After talking to AWS support I was pointed out the error.

In the example dictionary, every value is kept inside an array, and thus "clusterid" needed to be "clusterid" = "[]", and the quotes needed to be escaped.